# Running gitlab-ee on ubunutu 20.04 server

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab

I installed gitlab-ee successfully according to https://about.gitlab.com/install/#ubuntu .
after configuring /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb , I tried to access website using http://gitlab.mydomain.com . But it will be redirected to https://gitlab.example.com/ automatically .

How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be a simple enable.  In `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`, the variable `gitlab_url` should become `http://gitlab.mydomain.com`

It's possible that you've turned on some other variable with `example.com`?  There are many commented lines with seeded variables in `gitlab.rb`.